# What numbers (on my tuner) to tune my guitar to

Tags: guitar, tuning

Like on my electronic tuner I Have C3 C4 C5 E3 E4 etc so what numbers on notes am I supposed to tune my guitar too, I keep breaking,and loosening my strings ._.

Comment: My advice would be to use an [online guitar tuner](http://www.fender.com/community/guitar-tuner/) to generate the pitches you need to aim for -- then you can match the sound before fine-tuning with your electronic tuner.

Comment: When I tuned my guitar I got a online guitar tuner then pulled out my electric tuner to see what number that was and tuned that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

E2 is the bottom (fattest) string, followed by A2, D3, G3, B3 and the thin E is E4.              However, on a guitar tuner, there usually is a 'guitar setting' which recognises the actual open string notes.
The thing to be very careful of, as a beginner, is that an E note in one octave can sound like a different E. Indeed, to a tuner, play an E and it'll recognise E. Play a different E and it'll still tell you it's E. Obvious, maybe, but by then, you could have a string an octave too high. It happens !

Comment: For guitar specifically, the E2 at the fifth fret is the same note and octave as on the open A2. This pattern repeats, except on the B where the 4th fret is the same note and octave as open E4. This at least gives one a check against octave doubling or can get one into the ballpark and then fine-tune with the tuner.